# Data persistence for a quartz job which exits with an exception?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Suppose I have scheduled a quartz job which is marked with the PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute. This means that data added to the JobDataMap will be persisted between executions. I am wondering though if the job exits with an exception will the scheduler still persist the JobDataMap of the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a job is annotated with `PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute` and it exits with an exception, still its `JobDataMap` is persisted to re-execute it if a `recovery` or `fail-over` situation is encountered.

For instance, if user catches the exception and **modifies something in `JobDataMap`** and refires it again as below:

```
JobExecutionException e2 = new JobExecutionException(e);
// fix somekey in JobDataMap
dataMap.Put("sampleKey", "1");

// this job will refire immediately
e2.RefireImmediately = true;
```

In another case, where user has caught an exception and is not interested in running all triggers associated with this job, the **JobDataMap will not be persisted.**

```
e2.UnscheduleAllTriggers = true;
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! But what if the job exits with an exception different from JobExecutionException?

Comment: @MilenKovachev Any exception thrown during Job Execution is thrown as `SchedulerException` which is the base class of `JobExecutionException`. So it is eventually the same `JobExecutionException`